# How to focus to a web part in page

Tags: javascript, jquery, page-layout, html, client-side-rendering

I have a task to zoom in to a web part in mobile device. Our master page and page layout isn't mobile ready, but we provide users access to some SharePoint pages.

I tried to use this to focus (or zoom in) to the web part:

```
document.getElementById("WebPartWPQ1").focus();
```

But that only scroll down to that web part **vertically**. What I need is to align to the top left corner as the new (0, 0) coordinates in mobile browsers. How should I achieve that properly?